# stream socket reader receive 0 byte and app crash (windows phone 8)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

How do you handle a null data (0 byte) that's coming from the reader? My app keeps force closing when it receives null data. Here is my code:

```
int i = 0;

    private async void ReceiveData()
    {
        if (socket != null)
        {
            uint s = await dataReader.LoadAsync(1);
            string data = dataReader.ReadString(s);    
            Debug.WriteLine(s);
            if (data=="X")
            {
                i++;    
            }
            if (data == null)
            {
                // what should I put here?
            }
            txtMessage.Text = i.ToString();
        }
    }
```

I'm having trouble when my app receives null data and suddenly it is forced to close. Any idea what code to put when my app receives a null data and waits for the next incoming data?

In this case I want the dataReader to keep reading the incoming data even if the data is null (no data received) and wait until it gets the next incoming data. How would you do that?

Thank you

Comment: What is `dataReader`? What does the exception look like? (Please post the complete stack trace.)

Comment: dataReader = new DataReader(socket.InputStream);

Comment: That doesn't sound like a standard class I'm familiar with - what's the namespace?

Comment: it's windows.storage.streams

Comment: Got it, thanks. Looks like you want to check whether `s` is 0.

Comment: yeah I want to do something to prevent my app crashing when it receive s = 0 or no bytes were received from a bluetooth. How can I do it?

Comment: Well work out what you want to do if `s` is 0, and do it... I'm afraid I don't see how to help more. (Potentially loop while it's *not* 0, but it's hard to tell...)

Answer (score 0):

To repeat an action, use a `while` loop.

However, if you read zero bytes from a socket stream, then that means the socket has been closed and you should *stop* reading.

Comment: ok, I see now why my app was crash. Can you give me some hint where should I put the while loop?

Comment: The while loop should go around all the statements you want to repeat.